# Android array and resources

Tags: android, arrays, string

Whi with this code

```
public  final String[] array_titoli_serie_prima = new String[]{
        getResources().getString(R.string.titolo_p1),
        getResources().getString(R.string.titolo_p2),
        getResources().getString(R.string.titolo_p3),
        getResources().getString(R.string.titolo_p4),
        getResources().getString(R.string.titolo_p5),
        getResources().getString(R.string.titolo_p6),
        getResources().getString(R.string.titolo_p7),
        getResources().getString(R.string.titolo_p8),
        getResources().getString(R.string.titolo_p9),
        getResources().getString(R.string.titolo_p10),
        getResources().getString(R.string.titolo_p11),
        getResources().getString(R.string.titolo_p12),
        getResources().getString(R.string.titolo_p13),
        getResources().getString(R.string.titolo_p14),
        getResources().getString(R.string.titolo_p15),
        getResources().getString(R.string.titolo_p16),
        getResources().getString(R.string.titolo_p17),
        getResources().getString(R.string.titolo_p18),
        getResources().getString(R.string.titolo_p19),
        getResources().getString(R.string.titolo_p20),
        getResources().getString(R.string.titolo_p21),
        getResources().getString(R.string.titolo_p22)
    };
```

I have the error 03-20 00:46:02.120: E/AndroidRuntime(14847): java.lang.NullPointerException for all getResources line ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getResources()` is a method of `Context`, so you can only do it like that in a class instance which subclasses Context, like an `Activity`.

And actually you may want to look into String Array resources: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

Comment: but I have try also context. getResources().getString(R.string.titolo_p1) but I have di same error...

Comment: Hm. and is R surely not android.R?

Comment: I have resolved to this code 
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">                                        <item>Mercury</item>        <item>Venus</item>        <item>Earth</item></string-array></resources>